# Chernikov and Sylow

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ periodic (infinity). Let $\mathbb{P}$ is a set primes
numbers, $\pi \subseteq P$ and $\pi ^{\prime }=P-\pi$.

Let $O_{\pi }\left( G\right) =\left\langle N \ ;\ N\unlhd G, N \ \
is \ \pi -subgroup \ of\ G \ \right\rangle $

A subgoup $P$ de $G$ is called a Sylow $\pi$-subgrupo if $P$ is a
$\pi$-group and $P$ is maximal among the $\pi$-subgroups of $G$.

A Chernikov group is a group G that has a normal subgroup $N$ such
that $G/N$ is finite and N is a direct product of finitely many
quasicyclic groups, this is,  $N=C_{p_{1}^{\infty}} \times C_{p_{2}^{\infty}} \times \cdots \times
C_{p_{i}^{\infty}}$.

My question is:

Which the type of information I can have on G if $G/O_{p'}(G)$ is
Chernikov group?

I think I may have information about $P$ Sylow $p$-subgrupo of
$G$.

At least intuitively, I can have information?

Thanks in advance!